# Metodo .split de str en Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Actualmente me encuentro haciendo un laboratorio para la Universidad y se me pidio usar Python (2 o 3) en la herramienta colaboratory de google. En el codigo que tengo se recibe un archivo desde la maquina local de tipo YAML (como se ve mas adelante), estoy tratando de convertir el valor del diccionario que vendria siendo el texto en el archivo a una lista (1 fila = 1 elemento de la lista), para esto quiero usar el metodo .split de str, pero al usarlo me devuelve solo 1 elemento gigante con todas las lineas juntas, resulta que siguen existiendo los "\r\n" y ademas agrega "\" en algunas partes. hay alguna restriccion en cuanto al reemplazo de los "\algo" ? ya que .split funciona perfecto cuando pongo una letra u otro signo.

---

El archivo de texto YAML es el siguiente:

```
# Archivo de configuracion YAML para el simulador de cache
arquitectura:
tamano_palabra: 4 #bytes
tamano_bloque: 16 #bytes
cache_1: #requerido
bloques: 16
asociatividad: 2
tiempo_acceso: 1 #cycles
cache_2:
bloques: 64
asociatividad: 4
tiempo_acceso: 10 #cycles
cache_3:
bloques: 256
asociatividad: 8
tiempo_acceso: 100 #ciclos
mem_principal: #requerido
tiempo_acceso: 1000 #ciclos
```

---

El codigo que estoy usando es:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))

keys = list()

for archivo in uploaded.keys():
    keys.append(archivo)

print(keys[0])

texto = str(uploaded[keys[0]])
print(texto)

texto = texto.replace("b'", "")
print(texto)

texto = texto.split("\r\n")
print(texto)
```

---

Lo cual me arroja la siguiente salida:

```
ejemplo1.txt(text/plain) - 397 bytes, last modified: 5/1/2019 - 100% done
 Saving ejemplo1.txt to ejemplo1.txt
User uploaded file "ejemplo1.txt" with length 397 bytes
ejemplo1.txt
b'# Archivo de configuracion YAML para el simulador de cache\r\narquitectura:\r\ntamano_palabra: 4 #bytes\r\ntamano_bloque: 16 #bytes\r\ncache_1: #requerido\r\nbloques: 16\r\nasociatividad: 2\r\ntiempo_acceso: 1 #cycles\r\ncache_2:\r\nbloques: 64\r\nasociatividad: 4\r\ntiempo_acceso: 10 #cycles\r\ncache_3:\r\nbloques: 256\r\nasociatividad: 8\r\ntiempo_acceso: 100 #ciclos\r\nmem_principal: #requerido\r\ntiempo_acceso: 1000 #ciclos'
# Archivo de configuracion YAML para el simulador de cache\r\narquitectura:\r\ntamano_palabra: 4 #bytes\r\ntamano_bloque: 16 #bytes\r\ncache_1: #requerido\r\nbloques: 16\r\nasociatividad: 2\r\ntiempo_acceso: 1 #cycles\r\ncache_2:\r\nbloques: 64\r\nasociatividad: 4\r\ntiempo_acceso: 10 #cycles\r\ncache_3:\r\nbloques: 256\r\nasociatividad: 8\r\ntiempo_acceso: 100 #ciclos\r\nmem_principal: #requerido\r\ntiempo_acceso: 1000 #ciclos'
["# Archivo de configuracion YAML para el simulador de cache\\r\\narquitectura:\\r\\ntamano_palabra: 4 #bytes\\r\\ntamano_bloque: 16 #bytes\\r\\ncache_1: #requerido\\r\\nbloques: 16\\r\\nasociatividad: 2\\r\\ntiempo_acceso: 1 #cycles\\r\\ncache_2:\\r\\nbloques: 64\\r\\nasociatividad: 4\\r\\ntiempo_acceso: 10 #cycles\\r\\ncache_3:\\r\\nbloques: 256\\r\\nasociatividad: 8\\r\\ntiempo_acceso: 100 #ciclos\\r\\nmem_principal: #requerido\\r\\ntiempo_acceso: 1000 #ciclos'"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varias cosas:

- Lo primero, el fichero yaml que muestras no es yaml válido. En yaml la indentación tiene significado (al igual que en python) para agrupar los elementos que van dentro de una misma clave, pero tu fichero no muestra ninguna indentación.

  Sospecho que la indentación correcta sería la siguiente:

  ```
  # Archivo de configuracion YAML para el simulador de cache
  arquitectura:
    tamano_palabra: 4 #bytes
    tamano_bloque: 16 #bytes
  cache_1: #requerido
    bloques: 16
    asociatividad: 2
    tiempo_acceso: 1 #cycles
  cache_2:
    bloques: 64
    asociatividad: 4
    tiempo_acceso: 10 #cycles
  cache_3:
    bloques: 256
    asociatividad: 8
    tiempo_acceso: 100 #ciclos
  mem_principal: #requerido
    tiempo_acceso: 1000 #ciclos
  ```
- No es buena idea que intentes *parsear* por tí mismo un archivo yaml. El formato yaml tiene miles de sutilezas y variaciones, pues los elementos de cada clave podrían ser listas, cadenas, cadenas multi-línea, etc. y hay diferente sintaxis para cada cosa. Tener en cuenta todas las posibilidades es tremendamente complejo (una de las razones por las que algunos están en contra de este formato). No tiene sentido hacerlo tú mismo cuando ya existen módulos de terceros que lo hacen, como pyyaml.
- Incluso para un caso tan sencillo como es el tuyo, te merece la pena delegar en uno de estos módulos de terceros (ej: pyyaml), pues así ya no tienes que programar nada y te aseguras de que el resultado es correcto, aún si el yaml cambia y se complica más adelante.
- Además mencionas que usas collaboratory. ¡Resulta que en collaboratory ya tienes preinstalado pyyaml!

Por tanto tu código quedaría tan simple como:

```
import yaml
with open("ejemplo.yaml") as f:
  diccionario = yaml.load(f)
```

Y el resultado (variable `diccionario`) quedaría así:

```
{'arquitectura': {'tamano_bloque': 16, 'tamano_palabra': 4},
 'cache_1': {'asociatividad': 2, 'bloques': 16, 'tiempo_acceso': 1},
 'cache_2': {'asociatividad': 4, 'bloques': 64, 'tiempo_acceso': 10},
 'cache_3': {'asociatividad': 8, 'bloques': 256, 'tiempo_acceso': 100},
 'mem_principal': {'tiempo_acceso': 1000}}
```

Comment: Ohhh!! buenisima! probare esto de pyyaml. Y si, son las identaciones correctas, no se porque no se copiaron bien jajaja.
por otro lado, para usar el codigo que me comentas ambientado al hecho de subir un archivo desde la maquina local, habria que cambiar algo?

Comment: En principio no. En una celda del libro pones el código que sirve para subir el yaml, y ya en otra el código que yo te puse. El archivo que subas queda guardado en la máquina donde se está ejecutando tu notebook y puedes acceder a él desde cualquier otra celda (aunque si dejas pasar mucho tiempo, google apagará y borrará esa máquina, y cuando vayas a ejecutar el libro otra vez el fichero ya no estará, pero bastará que ejecutes de nuevo la celda que lo subía)

Answer (score 0):

Al hacer esto:

```
texto = str(uploaded[keys[0]])
```

conviertes todo en texto (incluyendo \r\n), al usar

```
texto = texto.split("\r\n")
```

buscas separar caracteres de control, que no están en tu texto. La solución es usar texto poniendo doble diagonal invertida, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
texto = texto.split("\\r\\n")
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias! asi si funciona!